# URL rewriting with variables using htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a `vendor_info.php` file in that am passing two variables category ID and vendor ID like `vendor_info.php?cat=1&vid=13`. Am using this code in htaccess file for rewriting

```
RewriteRule ^category/(.*)/(.*)-(.*)$ vendor_info.php?cat=$1&vid=$3
```

but its not redirecting. Can anyone help me for this please?

Comment: in 3rd position am using vendor id, 2nd position vendor name will come eg :/category/51/Vysaki-Jala-Udhyanavanam-5233

Comment: Try with `RewriteRule ^category/(.*)/(.*)-([0-9]+)$ vendor_info.php?cat=$1&vid=$2 [L]`

Comment: its not showing the proper result.

Comment: What do you expect it to "show"? you need to explain more. What are you doing, what are you linking to and what is the outcome?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like;

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ /vendor_info.php?cat=$1&vid=$2 [L]
```

This will rewrite (not redirect!) http://example.com/category/184/ where category is the category id and 184 is the vendor id, to /vendor_info.php?cat=category&vid=184

Comment: In what way is it not working? Can you please elaborate? 500 error, unexpected result, etc?

Comment: its not showing the result. i mean abbout the vendor its not showing details and scripts(css, js) also not loading.

Comment: Do you have a link? I'm really struggling to understand you.

Comment: http://www.example.com/vendor_info.php?cat=24&vid=2 this is my url. I want to rewrite this url to http://www.example.com/cat/24/2-vendor-name. Am using this code RewriteRule ^cat/(.*)/([0-9]+)-(.*)$ vendor_info.php?cat=$1&vid=$2 [L]. But not loading the result. Page is showing full blank.